# Calling previous version of Spring with exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

pom.xml is given as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jvoid</groupId>
    <artifactId>jvoidproducts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>jVoidProducts</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!--<org.springframework-version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>-->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jvoid</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistenceapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jvoid</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version><!--JavaEE7 onwards-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>

            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.Final</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build><finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName></build>
</project>
```

Upon running project with above pom I got following Exception:
Server used Tomcat v6.

**Stack Trace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:102)
    org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1366)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:148)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:98)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Above stack trace shows that `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment()` method does not exists. It shows that **at line 102** in method `configureScanner()` of class `org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser`, method  `getEnvironment()` of class `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate` is called.

When I checked the source code of above classes I found that:

In class `ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser`(of release **5.0.1.Release**), at line 102(in method `configureScanner()`) there is no call to `getEnvironment()` method of class `BeanDefinitionParserDelegate`.

But when I checked, I found that in Release **4.3.5.Release**(or it may be **4.3.13**), it is present **at line 102** but not in the releases after that.

**As according to pom given above I am using spring version 5.0.1.Release so why it calling getEnvironment() method of previous version(4.3.5.Release)?**

The method calling trace for above error stack is given as(as what I checked)(may be it is helpful for answer in any way):

> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory()
>   is called in org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh()
>   at line 454 in versions upto 4.1.9 but not  afterwards--------->
>   AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory()  is called at 540 upto 
>   v4.1.9----->XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions() is called 
>   at line 129 upto 
>   v5.0.0.RC2-------->XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions() is 
>   called at line 94 seen in 
>   v5.0.1.Release------>AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions() is called at 125 of class XmlWebApplicationContext in 
>   v5.0.1.Release---->AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions() 
>   is called at 194 of AbstractBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release---->AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions() 
>   is called at 223 of AbstractBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release------------->XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions() is called at line 187 of class of AbstractBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release----->XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions() is 
>   called at line 303 of class XmlBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release------------>XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions()
>   is called at line 335 of class XmlBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   V5.0.1.Release----------->XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions() is called at line 391 of class XmlBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release------------->DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions() is called at line 507 of class XmlBeanDefinitionReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release----------->DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions() is called at line 98 of class DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release---------->DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.arseBeanDefinitions()
>   is called at line 148 of class DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release--------->BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement() is called at line 178 of class DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader in 
>   v5.0.1.Release---------->BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement()
>   is called at line 1352 of class BeanDefinitionParserDelegate in 
>   v5.0.1.Release-------->NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse() is called at 
>   line 1366 of class BeanDefinitionParserDelegate in 
>   v5.0.1.Release-------->ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse() is 
>   called at line 74 of class NamespaceHandlerSupport in 
>   v5.0.1.Release------------>ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner()
>   is called at line 84 of class ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser upto 
>   v4.1.0.Release--------->BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.getEnvironment() 
>   is called at line 102 of class ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser upto
>
> > v4.1.0.Release

Comment: Do `mvn dependency:tree` and check your dependencies. You are probably pulling in old dependencies due to the Spring WebFlow dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks! I solved it by the dependency:tree command mentioned by you. It was not due to spring webflow dependency but due to some others. If you put this comment as answer I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mvn dependency:tree` you can check which dependencies are being pulled in and which transitive dependencies are getting pulled in. You can use that the get a clue on what to tune.